# Search Number in Url

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php
$url = "savings.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/15-11-201120Rs.1500.txt";
if (strpos($url, "505153")!==false){
    echo "Number Here";
}
else {
   echo "No Number Here :(";
}

?>
```

I found number of prize bond in this url
http://savings.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/15-11-201120Rs.1500.txt

but i fail i not know how code use php to find number

number who i found is '   505153   '

Comment: *"I found number of prize bond in this url http://savings.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/15-11-201120Rs.1500.txt"* - So why aren't you using that same "URL" in your variable declaration? Plus, what you done to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is check '505153' in url or not, i think you need check '505153' in txt file. You can try this

```
$content = trim(file_get_contents('http://savings.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/15-11-201120Rs.1500.txt'));
if ($content) {
    if (strpos($content, "505153") !== false) {
        echo "Number Here";
    } else {
        echo "No Number Here :(";
    }
} else {
    echo "No Content found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php **curl**  or **file_get_contents()** to get the bond data from the specified url before finding your number in the data.
When I tried the bellow code I got **Number Here** message. Hope this help

```
$url = 
file_get_contents("http://savings.gov.pk/wp-
content/uploads/2017/03/15-11-
201120Rs.1500.txt");
//then try to find your number on the text
if (strpos($url, "505153")!==false){
 echo "Number Here";
}
else {
echo "No Number Here :(";
}
```

**Ref.**

*curl:* http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

*file_get_contents:*
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php